# need to get date from a name in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

im trying to get a date from a name i have got the date but i need it to be in yyyy-mm-dd format.

what i get:
20221201

what i need:
2022-12-01

please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be as simple as this ... assuming the date string is the last 8 characters

**Example**

```
Select try_convert(date,right('typographical_dismal_subjoinByapostrophize1_12345_20221201',8))
```

**Resutls**

```
2022-12-01
```

Comment: But that would return a `date`, and maybe a string is needed?

Comment: @Luuk True.  Just going off the title "need to get date ..."

Answer (score 0):

This should work ,

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,RIGHT('ABCDEF20221201',8),103)